# Dynamically sort object by key provided in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

What's wrong with this code? Why cant it sort the array according to the `a` key of the object?

It works when using dot notation in the condition but I want to use the second parameter in the condition instead of dot notation. Please help me getting the result.

This works:

```
if (objSort[i][`sortBy`] > objSort[j][`sortBy`]) {
  [objSort[i], objSort[j]] = [objSort[j], objSort[i]]
}
```

This does not work:

```js
function sortData(objSort, sortBy) {
  for (let i = 0; i < objSort.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < objSort.length; j++) {
      if (objSort[i][`sortBy`] > objSort[j][`sortBy`]) {
        [objSort[i], objSort[j]] = [objSort[j], objSort[i]]

      }
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
}

const data = [{ a: 4, b: 5 }, { a: 1, b: 10}, { a: 2, b: 5 }, { a: 14, b: 15 }, { a: 12, b: 3 }];
sortData(data,'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy` is your variable name, so remove it from the template literal:

```
if (objSort[i][sortBy] > objSort[j][sortBy]) {
```

That being said, your code is *much* more complex than it needs to be - there's no need for two loops and reorganising the array - just use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const sortData = (objSort, sortBy) => objSort.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy] - b[sortBy]);

const data = [{ a: 4, b: 5 }, { a: 1, b: 10}, { a: 2, b: 5 }, { a: 14, b: 15 }, { a: 12, b: 3 }];
const result = sortData(data,'a');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP hasn't yet heard of nlogn...